# Programmatically sort jquery-ui sortable?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a bunch of divs inside a `display:flex` parent div. The parent div is sortable with jquery-ui's `sortable` function.

As well as allowing the user to sort, I would like to add some buttons that do an animated sort.

For example, with this HTML:

```
<div class="sortable">
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
  <div id="div3"></div>
  <div id="div4"></div>
  <div id="div5"></div>
</div>
```

I would like a button that when pressed would animate moving div1 to be between div4 and div5, moving smoothly (in fact, a little erratically as if it were being moved by hand would be even better) and shifting all the divs it passes, so it looks as if it were being moved by hand.

Is this possible using jquery-ui's sortable(), or am I better off building a custom solution?

Comment: This is not possible with sortable. It is part of a UI and relies on Drag and Drop actions. UI Animate and Position can help you do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  function arrange(obj, pre) {
    obj = $(obj);
    var t = $("[id^='div']:eq(" + pre + ")");
    obj.animate({
      top: t.position().top + "px"
    }, {
      duration: 1000,
      step: function(i) {
        $(this).position({
          my: "left top",
          at: "left bottom",
          of: t,
        });
      },
      complete: function() {
        obj.detach().css("top", "").insertAfter(t);
      }
    });
  }

  $(".sortable").sortable().disableSelection();

  $("#arrange").click(function() {
    arrange($("#div1"), 3);
  });
});
```

```css
.sortable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.sortable div {
  margin: 0 3px 3px 3px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="sortable">
  <div id="div1" class="ui-state-default">Item 1</div>
  <div id="div2" class="ui-state-default">Item 2</div>
  <div id="div3" class="ui-state-default">Item 3</div>
  <div id="div4" class="ui-state-default">Item 4</div>
  <div id="div5" class="ui-state-default">Item 5</div>
</div>
<button class="btn" id="arrange">Arrange</button>
```

Built from https://css-tricks.com/jquery-ui-position-function/

**Update**

```js
$(function() {
  function swap(a, b, ms) {
    console.log("Swap:", a.attr("id"), "with", b.attr("id"));
    a.animate({
      top: b.position().top + "px"
    }, {
      duration: ms,
      step: function(i) {
        $(this).position({
          my: "left top",
          at: "left bottom",
          of: b,
        });
      },
      complete: function() {
        a.detach().css("top", "").insertAfter(b);
      }
    });
  }

  function arrangeAfter(a, b) {
    var n = a.next();
    for (var c = parseInt(n.attr("id").slice(-1)); n.index() <= b.index(); c++) {
      swap(a, n, 400);
      n = $("#div" + (c + 1));
    }
  }

  $(".sortable").sortable().disableSelection();

  $("#arrange").click(function() {
    arrangeAfter($("#div1"), $("#div4"));
  });
});
```

```css
.sortable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.sortable div {
  margin: 0 3px 3px 3px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="sortable">
  <div id="div1" class="ui-state-default">Item 1</div>
  <div id="div2" class="ui-state-default">Item 2</div>
  <div id="div3" class="ui-state-default">Item 3</div>
  <div id="div4" class="ui-state-default">Item 4</div>
  <div id="div5" class="ui-state-default">Item 5</div>
</div>
<button class="btn" id="arrange">Arrange</button> <button class="btn" id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: This is pretty close, and I guess I can make it do the skip by animating it to each div in turn for a split second in order to make them shift as it moves between them. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm this is going to be more complicated than I thought, as in my scenario it is 100 30px divs in a wrapped `display:flex` container. The divs might be 5 rows of 20 when displayed, which means that diagonal animation is a possibility, and I can't just animate it to the next div, I either need to calculate the path of the animation to work out where the next div is, or see which one I'm over at each step of the animation somehow.

Comment: Also I'm having trouble with position().left I think because the container has a % left and right margin. I'm trying to figure that out now.

Comment: @BenHolness I updated another example with a `swap` function so you can loop through each position. `flex` will give you some issues, but there are ways to address it.

Comment: I've managed to overcome the flex positioning problems, but I can't use step by step for the diagonals, however your answer does basically what I was looking for and has me on the right path! Thanks :)